# Web scraping com Python (Selenium e Request)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, request, scraping, beautifulsoup

Olá,

Estou tentando realizar um web scraping em uma página protegida por login, já consegui realizar o acesso tanto via Request, quanto via Selenium, o problema se dá após o login.

A página é a seguinte: https://eduardocavalcanti.com/login
Após o login, ele redireciona para essa página automaticamente: https://eduardocavalcanti.com/dashboard

Entretanto, quando faço o login via navegador, se eu pedir para acessar a página https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/petr/ ele acessa sem problemas por conta de que já realizei o login.

Porém isso não está funcionando com o **Request**. Mesmo eu solicitando para ele acessar a página https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/petr/ ele vai para alguma outra página.

Sou novato nessa área, já realizei algumas consultas, mas não encontrei uma base para referência.

código do Request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

loginPage = 'https://eduardocavalcanti.com/login/'
protectedPage = 'https://eduardocavalcanti.com/dashboard'
petrUrl = 'https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/petr/'
payload = {
    'user_login': 'meu_email@gmail.com',
    'password': 'minhasenha'
}

sess = requests.session()
sess.post(loginPage, data=payload)
#petr = sess.get(protectedPage)
petr = sess.get(petrUrl )
soup = BeautifulSoup(petr.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

código do Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/itsa/") 
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("user_login")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("user_pass")
username.send_keys("meu_email@hotmail.com")
password.send_keys("minha_senha")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/petr/")
DadosEmpresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text
#DadosEmpresa = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body")
#for item in DadosEmpresa:
    #print(item.text)
```

O problema que encontro é que a estrutura que o Selenium retorna daria trabalho para colocar em um dicionário em Python. **Há alguma forma do Selenium retornar as tabelas da página em um formato mais estruturado?** Assim eu poderia utilizar BeautifulSoup.

**Em relação ao Request, será que há algum bloqueio no site que impede dele acessar a pagina?** Já tentei utilizar cookies, dar timesleep e nada deu certo.

Comment: **Pedro**, não da pra utilizar os dois módulos juntos? Tipo: `browser = webdriver.Firefox() browser.get("...") soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')`??

Comment: Caralho maluko, nem tinha pensado nisso. Como disse, sou novato, mas deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: @PedroCosta, inclua os headers do user-agent no seu get, isso ajuda o seu robô a ficar parecido com o acesso pelo navegador e evita bloqueio do site.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de você transformar uma tabela HTML em um formato mais estruturado é com a biblioteca Pandas.
Como não tenho acesso a área logada, vou colocar um exemplo de código para você adaptar para a sua tabela:

```
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/itsa/") 
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("user_login")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("user_pass")
username.send_keys("meu_email@hotmail.com")
password.send_keys("minha_senha")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("https://eduardocavalcanti.com/an_fundamentalista/petr/")
DadosEmpresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text

# Aqui você utiliza o Pandas para transformar a tabela HTML em um DataFrame
df_tabela = pd.read_html(DadosEmpresa)        # carrega tabela HTML em um DataFrame do Pandas
df = df_tabela[['id da empresa','nome da empresa','descricao']]  # alterar para ser igual aos titulos da sua tabela no site
df.columns = ['id','empresa','descricao']        # coloca nome que quiser nas variaveis
print(df)
```

Segue um tutorial para te auxiliar a usar o Pandas:
[How to use Pandas read_html to Scrape Data from HTML Tables](https://www.marsja.se/how-to-use-pandas-read_html-to-scrape-data-from-html-tables/)

[Web Scraping com Python, Selenium e Pandas - Código Fonte TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxl5jUltHBo)